# Purpose of java.library.path

Tags: java, jvm

Perhaps this is a duplicate question, but I havn't found something by myself.

Basically I have an understanding problem.

I have an application which works fine when I call it as follows:

```
java -Duser.dir="some path" -Djava.library.path="pathToDLL1;pathToDLL2;pathToMyDir" classToCall par1
```

With the call above my application will start and run.

My problem in understanding is within the *pathToMyDir* directory (the content of this directory is mainly some needed dll's).

When I start the same application with following command it will fail.

```
java -Duser.dir="some path" -Djava.library.path="pathToMyDir;pathToDLL1;pathToDLL2" classToCall par1
```

I'm not sure if this is because of some dependencies, but I thought the java.library.path is mainly used to tell java where to look for external libraries. Or is this wrong? Is there also some order information hidden?

Comment: Jeff Storey is right. You should never include jar files to java.library.path: they are simply ignored there. I do not know why does your application fail. Try to check the path again. Try to remove the Jar1 and Jar2 from java.library.path and put them to -cp (classpath).

Comment: I think he is right for sure and I'm truly wrong. I made a terrible typo. It shouldn't be pathToJar it should be pathToDll. Of course I won't put a path to a jar into the library path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-Djava.library.path` is used for pointing to native system libraries (dll or so files). It points to a directory and calls to native code that use `System.loadLibrary` look in that directory for the native libs.

The project dependencies (jar files) should be specified on the application's classpath, not in this location.